# How to write numbers inside polygon (pentagon, hexagon, octagon)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

There are many [node shapes](https://web.mit.edu/spin_v4.2.5/share/graphviz/doc/html/info/shapes.html), so is it possible (and how) to write numbers inside any other shape apart from a circle and rectangle?

I have created new commands using tikz package. I can write inside the circle (and change radius), and rectangle (change side length), but not sure how to write inside e.g. hexagon polygon. I get an error when using \newcmdd{2}.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle,fill=white,draw,minimum size=5.5mm,inner sep=0.0pt,text=black] (char) {#1};}}

\newcommand*\newcmd[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=rectangle,fill=white,draw,minimum size=5mm,inner sep=0.0pt,text=black] (char) {#1};}}
    
% \newcommand*\newcmdd[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    %   \node[shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, ,fill=white,draw, minimum size=5mm,inner sep=0.0pt,text=black] (char) {#1};}}


\begin{document}

\circled{2}
\newcmd{2}
% \newcmdd{2}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to add `\usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric}` ;-) https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.regular:polygon

Comment: @Rmano, thanks. Works ok

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144193/how-do-i-put-a-die-roll-at-the-top-of-each-page

Answer (score 2):

The code gives the errors:

```
lalla.tex|19 error| Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/regular polygon sides', to which you passed '6', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
lalla.tex|19 error| Package tikz Error: Unknown shape ``regular polygon.'' Using ``rectangle'' instead.
```

So the "regular polygon" is not recognized. The problem is that, as you can see in the [example on the manual](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.regular:polygon), you need to add

```
 \usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric}
```

in the preamble, after loading Ti*k*Z.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can add `shape border rotate=<angle>` to the node options if you want to rotate the node (but not its contents).

Note that `minimum width` affects the circumcircle, whereas `inner sep` affects the incircle.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum width=2cm, draw}]
\draw[help lines](-1,-1)grid(11,1);
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, red] at (0,0) {3};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4, orange] at (2,0) {4};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5, yellow] at (4,0) {5};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, green] at (6,0) {6};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=7, blue] at (8,0) {7};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8, violet] at (10,0) {8};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```